# Differences in interactions of light with different mediums

Tags: visible-light, water, scattering, atmospheric-science, diffusion

I am trying to figure out this problem, I apologize in advance if the question is silly.
If i am correct sunsets are red because red light doesnt get diffounded as much as blue light, which eventually bounces off the atmosphere. Underwater, on the other hand, its the blue light being predominant, this fact makes me a bit confused: shouldnt the mechanism be similar to what happens in the atmosphere, with the red light, being less affected by molecules, eventually becoming predominant underwater aswell?
Hope i have been clear and someone could answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

In the atmosphere (a gas of many small particles), scattering is dominant. Blue scatters more than red. So, during a sunset, red is the predominant color to reach your eye.

In liquid water (a thick medium of slightly absorbing molecules, but no optical interfaces), absorption is dominant. Red is absorbed more than blue. So, underwater, blue is the predominant color to reach your eye.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. Something similar happens with Neptune. Blue light doesn't reach it, only red, but it is composed of methane, which absorbs red light, making it appear blue, The opposite light color of red. That's like saying when it's dark in a room, it's not because there is black light, but it's because of the lack of it.